# Prevent div width from shrinking smaller than content

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` that can contain any number of `inline-block` `div` tags that contain content. These inner content containers will have unknown widths.

When the width of the window shrinks smaller than the width of the container `div`, the inline `div` tags begin to stack.

How can I prevent this? I'd like the container `div` to be not allowed to shrink any smaller than the width of its contents, adding scrollbars when necassary.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAWRX/
Shrink the width of the `Result` window and you'll see the container shrinks as well, forcing the content containers to stack.

Comment: Will you update your question to include the code snippets required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: There is already a JSFiddle link that directly reproduces the problem.

Comment: A JSFiddle link is a nice addition to an otherwise complete question, but it cannot be the only place that the code is posted. Stack Overflow questions should included everything needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to see the markup involved with this problem, click on the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Jesse, the community has guidelines regarding this issue. Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) for details. I am glad you found your answer, but you can expect your questions to be downvoted and/or closed in the future if you fail to heed the information provided in the link above.

Comment: `This can be a great bonus for the folks trying to recreate and solve your problem - but shouldn't be the only description of your problem. If jsbin goes away, your question and its answers should still make sense.` Thanks for helping to make this community better. Asking people to leave is neither productive or helpful, especially when people are here trying to help you.

Comment: The problem description is stated very clearly here in SO. The JSFiddle is only an example, not the problem itself. Once again, you are both making a deal out of nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to your container style and add `white-space: normal;` to your content style.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSV9N/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Don't know how I missed that...I didn't know that white-space inherits. Cheers.